# jquery slider and wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider, anythingslider

I'm pretty new to wordpress, html, css, and javascript and would love your help if possible:

I'm trying to create a dual slider for the featured content area of my blog where there will be three featured youtube videos on the left slider, and the post excerpt on the right slider.  [Here's how I picture it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrvBO.jpg)

I think i'm doing this inefficiently at the moment; using [dualslider](http://www.hugoandcat.com/DualSlider/)

Right now I have three divs on the right panel, one for each post where the_excerpt() is being output in each div:

```
<div class="detail" >
      <?php $args=array('tag' => 'Featured1', 'showposts'=>1, 'caller_get_posts'=>1);
               $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                      if( $my_query->have_posts() ) 
                {
                      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                      <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" <?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                      <h3><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h3>
                        <?php endwhile;
                }
                      wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div><!--END detail1-->
```

And three divs on the left, one for each video where the_content is being output to each div:

```
<div class="detail" >
      <?php $args=array('tag' => 'Featured1', 'showposts'=>1, 'caller_get_posts'=>1);
               $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                      if( $my_query->have_posts() ) 
                {
                      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                      <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" <?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                      <h3><?php the_content(); ?></h3>
                        <?php endwhile;
                }
                      wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div><!--END detail1-->
```

The three posts that I want featured are each tagged Featured1, Featured2, and Featured3, and the post content is just the iframe youtube embed code followed by whatever I want to be in the right content panel.

Finally, aside from it being difficult to format the carousel size of the videos given i don't really understand the dualslider javascript file, my other problem is that I need the currently playing video to be paused when you move from slide to slide similar to the functionality provided in AnythingSlider (http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/#panel1-4).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `caller_get_posts` is deprecated.

Comment: I think the whole thing is garbage, but what should i use instead?

Comment: Well, to be honest, your approach might not be the best. You should use only one loop for performance. Then, if you're new to all this, I suggest you start with something simpler. This is going to get too complicated...

Comment: I don't become discouraged easily. if you would in fact like to help me shoot me an email and I can better explain to you what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

https://gist.github.com/1848388

I've added the query and loops php into the index.html demo file.

This is the demo pack I downloaded... [Dual Slider Demo File](http://www.hugoandcat.com/DualSlider/dualSlider.zip)

I have not tested it so it may not work ha, and I've adjust your query to retrieve the latest 3 posts with the tag 'Featured'.

Also instead of using `<?php the_content(); ?>` for the image or video, why not use a custom field, this way you can still have the full article content in your post.

If you use `<?php the_content(); ?>` for the featured image or video in the slider, then all your post content will feed into that area, which could be a pain if you have lots of text and other images in your post.

So I've included the custom field in my [gist](https://gist.github.com/1848388), replacing `<?php the_content(); ?>`, all you have to do is create a custom field called...

**Slider Featured Image**

...and paste the image code or video embed code into this. Once you've created this custom field, **Slider Featured Image** will be saved and you will be able to select it from a dropdown in the post editor on other features.

I've commented through out the [gist](https://gist.github.com/1848388) so you know whats going on.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!  I will test it as the replacement for my jimmy-rigged AnythingSlider.

Comment: Give me a shout if you get stuck, or want to use a new jquery slider instead of dualslider.

Comment: Thanks. Take a stab? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729134/jquery-slider-anythingslider-video-functionality